# Stop icons from changing between steps Angular Material Stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material

By default the icons change from either done to editable when navigating between steps. Is it possible to stop this change from happening and instead keep the icons as the step numbers?

Answer (score 3):

```
<ng-template matStepperIcon="edit" let-index="index">
{{index +1}}
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your contribution. Please add an explanation to your code so that others can learn from your solution. Code only solutions are not always helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a little hacky but you can just put `completed="false"` on each of your `<mat-step>` tags and that will force it to stay uncompleted and also keep the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.

Template:

```xml
<mat-horizontal-stepper (selectionChange)="stepperSelectionChange($event, stepper)" [linear]="true" #stepper>
```

Component:

```js
stepperSelectionChange($event: StepperSelectionEvent, stepper: MatHorizontalStepper): void {
  if ($event.previouslySelectedIndex > $event.selectedIndex) {
    stepper.steps.forEach((item, index) => {
      if ($event.selectedIndex <= index) {
        item.completed = false;
        item.editable = false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```